# PHP process takes a long time to finish, how can I farm it off to a worker

Tags: php

I have a lot of calculations to do on a single thread (request/response). How can I multi-thread this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cant multi-thread, it can fork - but only when not going through apache!

Look at using a Worker system, like 
[PHP-Resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque)

It makes life so much easier :)

Answer (score 1):

**PHP CAN MULTITHREAD**

pthreads is not an interface to Posix Threads, but an Object Orientated Threading API for PHP 5.3+

http://php.net/pthreads

That is not to say that it is a good idea to create threads in direct response to a web request, but as a matter of fact; **PHP can multithread**.

Answer (score 0):

- Inter-Process Communication: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php
- interface to pthreads in PHP scripts: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php